# Does any style guide prefer < over > for readability?

Tags: coding-style, expression, comparison-operators, code-readability

For coding a relational expression, do any authoritative standards or style guides or field studies recommend less-than over greater-than?

For example, prefer `(0 <= x && x < 1)` to `(x >= 0 && x < 1)`.

Because we commonly read left-to-right and commonly count upwards, aligning these should increase readability, particularly for elaborate boolean expressions.

( https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/190311/what-is-best-in-a-if-condition-position-size-or-size-position-and-why has some debate, but doesn't cite reputable sources.)

Comment: I think it is a matter of personal preference. I find that the variable being tested on the left side `x >= 0` is clearer and more easily understood than `0 < x`, but maybe that's just because I always code it that way.

Comment: @jalynn2: I agree: for tiny expressions readability is no concern.  Multiline monsters are what worry me.  I disagree: surely _some_ organization has tried to measure this, thereby elevating it above personal preference.

Comment: Multiline monster relational expressions are unreadable, regardless of the order. The code should be restructured if they are present.

Comment: here is a book with ideas for accomplishing readability in situations like you reference: [link]http://books.google.com/books/about/Clean_Code.html?

Comment: If this means "Clean Code: A Handbook of Agile Software Craftsmanship", then sadly neither the index nor the table of contents nor fulltext search of Martin's mighty tome mentioned anything about compound expressions.

Comment: No, it does not deal with complex expressions, it is all about writing code that is readable. So, instead of a multi-line monster expression that will be difficult to read regardless of which way the comparison goes, break the expression into logical chunks and refactor each chunk into a method with a descriptive name `if (temperatureIsBelowFreezing(x) || weightExceedsLimit(y,z) && excessPaymentIsAuthorized(a,b)) {...`

Answer (score 0):

The answer, briefly, is no.  Here's probably why:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1186084/2097284 suggested that Martin Fowler's "Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code", like "Clean Code" in the comments above and who knows how many other books, advocates splitting elaborate boolean expressions, with or without comparison operators, into parts with descriptive names.  (Unlike, say, that sentence.)  So it's too narrow a question to be worth the expense of formal research.